# How to do SQL's GROUP BY using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, group-by, grouping

I'd like to SELECT rows from a database table and group them using PHP instead of SQL based on a parameter (in this case by item).

SQL:

```
Clothes table

 id  item     owner
 1   shoes     joe 
 2   pants     joe
 3   hat       joe
 4   pants     joe
 5   hat       tom

SELECT * from Clothes where owner='joe'

 1   shoes     joe 
 2   pants     joe
 3   hat       joe
 4   pants     joe
```

Here's how I'd like the results to look after using PHP instead of SQL's `GROUP BY item`

PHP :

```
 1   shoes     joe 
 2   pants     joe   //count 2
 3   hat       joe
```

I'm sure there is a PHP array function for this I'm just not familiar, thoughts?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this in php?

Comment: SQL will be more efficient and cause less headaches than going with a PHP solution. I know this from experience as I tried something similar before using multidimensional arrays - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318052/retrieving-values-from-a-php-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: @JonathanKuhn @jasper My actual data to `group by` is by date. I would like to do a query to get all items for a user then display them as grouped by date as well as display them un-grouped. If I do the `group by` using SQL I will lose the individual items and the data will be aggregated and I'll have to do 2 SQL queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to exploit the uniqueness of array keys:

```
$grouped = array();

while ($row = $db->fetchResult()) {  // or however you get your data
    if (isset($grouped[$row['item']])) {
        $grouped[$row['item']]['count']++;
    } else {
        $grouped[$row['item']] = $row + array('count' => 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you explain briefly what this code is doing? also, can I use a foreach loop instead of a while loop?

Comment: Sure, you can use any kind of loop. The "magic" is simply in `$grouped[ $row['item'] ]`. It takes the `item` value of each row and uses it as index for the new `$grouped` array. Rows with the same `item` will fall on the same index. In that case we just increment a counter.

Comment: Can add an $index++ to avoid: `Notice: Undefined index`

Answer (score 1):

Using pseucode for the database access functions, I believe this should work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from Clothes where owner='joe'";
$res = query($sql);
$arr = array();    

while ($row = $res->fetch())
{
    $arr[] = $row['item'];
}

$arr = array_unique($arr);
```

You should note that this might give you a "sparse array" (in other words, there may be gaps in the keys). And as said in the comments, it's usually better to do this in SQL if you have that option. Even if that means executing two similar queries.

Comment: -@jasper thanks, why is two similar SQL queries better than 1 query followed by parsing the results in PHP?

Comment: You had me there for a second, I answered because I was taught to work that way rather than because I knew exactly why it was that way. However, after thinking about it, one reason might be that it becomes code that is much easier to make mistakes in once you want to store any more information than just the sort by attribute like I do here. Another is that while two queries might take longer because of double disk access, it does the sorting more efficiently (if given correct indexes and all that) and might not need double disk access if it caches correctly.

Comment: ...[cont'd] Finally, you're just not supposed to second-guess the efficiency of your database once it is set up correctly. It can (and will) do a lot of optimization meaning that your guessing will just about always be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
function group($items, $field) {
    $return = array();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $key = $item[$field];

        if (isset($return[$key])) {
            $return[$key]['count']++;
        } else {
            $return[$key] = $item;
            $return[$key]['count'] = 1;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

print_r(group($results, "item"));
```